# Reading a specific file from a .tar file via readRDS

Tags: r, tar

Suppose I have a file `data.tar` and within this `.tar` file I have a file, called `file_1.rds`. Is there a way to read `file_1.rds` (via `readRDS()`) without first untaring `data.tar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a bit tricky but the following works:

```
tar_filename = 'data.tar'
rds_name = 'file_1.rds'

con = pipe(paste('tar xf', shQuote(tar_filename), '-O' , shQuote(rds_name)), 'rb')
result = readRDS(gzcon(con))
close(con)
```